# grpc-binder: how to send Parcelable from server to client

Tags: android, grpc-java, android-binder

Parcelable data from client to server can use ParcelableUtils.metadataKey to build grpc [Metadata headers].

but, how to send Parcelable data from server to client??

[Metadata headers] is only client to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metadata is available just before the request (i.e., headers), or just before or after the response (i.e., headers or trailers).

The basic approach is the same in all the cases: use an interceptor. But how you use an interceptor and communicate with the interceptor varies between client and server.

The [header example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/header) shows a server interceptor adding metadata to response headers:

```java
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      final Metadata requestHeaders,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    return next.startCall(new SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
      @Override
      public void sendHeaders(Metadata responseHeaders) {
        responseHeaders.put(CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY, "customRespondValue");
        super.sendHeaders(responseHeaders);
      }
    }, requestHeaders);
  }
```

That approach is the same independent of the type of Metadata (text, binary, or Parcelable). The only difference for the different types of Metadata is the construction of the `Metadata.Key`.

But with Binder, you are probably wanting the gRPC service to compute the Parcelable to respond with. For that, you need to pass a mutable API for the service to update.

```java
  public static final Context.Key<AtomicReference<YourParcelable>> MY_KEY
      = Context.key("myparcelable"); // the string is just for debugging

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      final Metadata requestHeaders,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    // Context is immutable, so we put a mutable value inside it.
    final AtomicReference<YourParcelable> p = new AtomicReference<>();
    Context context = Context.current().withValue(MY_KEY, p);
    return Contexts.interceptCall(context, new SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
      @Override
      public void sendHeaders(Metadata responseHeaders) {
        YourParcelable yp = p.get();
        if (yp != null) {
          responseHeaders.put(CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY, yp);
        }
        super.sendHeaders(responseHeaders);
      }
    }, requestHeaders);
  }

// In the service implementation before sending a response:
MyInterceptor.MY_KEY.get().set(yourParcelable);
```

Comment: When I try this code, I am advised that I am unable to create a `SimpleForwardingServerCall` : the ctor appears to be protected.

Comment: The constructor for SimpleForwardingServerCall is `protected`. So you have to extend the class. These classes here are anonymous classes extending SimpleForwardingServerCall.